# UTF-8 Bad Encoding when Using ZF2 dbAdapter for mySQL for Update

Tags: mysql, pdo, encoding, utf-8, zend-framework2

I am getting the Exception when I attempt to update the record with "tableGateway" object:

```
Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\InvalidQueryException
Statement could not be executed 
(HY000 - 1300 - Invalid utf8 character string: 'C`\xC3`\xB3`digo')
```

I have the following table structure with data in mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `clientes` (
    `Código` int,
    `Nome` varchar(50),
    `Descricao` varchar(150)
   ....
);

INSERT INTO `clientes` (`Código`, `Nome`, `Descricao`)
VALUES (1, 'Test Nome', 'Test Descricao');
```

The database encoding is 'latin1', but the database configuration is as shown:

```
'mycnn'    => array(
              'driver'         => 'pdo',
              'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname={$mydb};host={$myhost}',
              'username'       => '{$myuser}',
              'password'       => '{$mypassword}',
              'driver_options' => array(
                    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
                ),
            )
```

As you can see the above scenario, I have setup the driver for "UTF-8", the column name "Código" has a special character and renaming this column is not an option.

The syntax that I am using for updating in the model is:

```
$set = array("Nome" => "Edited Test");
$where = array("Código" => 1);

$this->tableGateway->update($set, $where);
```

After that, the ZF is parsing the SQL throwing the Exception:

```
UPDATE "clientes" SET "Nome" = 'Edited Test' WHERE "C`\xC3`\xB3`digo" = 1
```

I have also removed the UTF-8 option, since the catalog is "latin1_swedish_ci" without success.

I would appreciate anyone who gives me a hint how to face this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Cesar, can you emphasize that you are getting an exception? It isn't clear when skimming your question.

Comment: Hopefully you can steer towards UTF8 rather than away. Going UTF8 top to bottom can resolve a lot of encoding issues.

Comment: I have tried removing UTF-8 and also convert the string `utf8_decode("Código")`, but the column name becomes 'C\`ó\`digo', with 2 backquotes between the special character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your database encoding type is `UTF-8`.

```
'driver_options' => array(
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
),
```

Make sure fields have `utf8_general_ci`.

In your layout phtml head has

```
<meta charset='utf-8'>
```

**Updated**

As you said you are not able to change encoding to `utf-8` so use one of the following commands using `driver_options`

```
'SET NAMES \'latin1\'' or 'SET CHARACTER SET \'latin1\''
```

For more details check out the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) please!

**When problem with column name which has latin1 characters**

Just pass the condition as string not an array as the second argument into `TableGateway`'s `update()` method. But you must set this `'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''` in your driver_options.

```
$id = 1;
$where = "Código = {$id}";

// Or use this way
$where = "Código = 1";

$this->tableGateway->update($set, $where);
```

Comment: the 'driver_option' is setup as the OP says. Furthermore, I am not using a view, but the output is rendered to controller via console / cron. Finally, fields and catalog are LATIN1 and I can't change it since I'm not the DBA.

Comment: I have tried removing UTF-8 and also convert the string `utf8_decode("Código")`, but the column name becomes 'C\`ó\`digo', with 2 backquotes between the special character, giving as result "UNKNOWN COLUMN".

Comment: Finally I could solve using the plain string "Código = {$id}", then I have upvoted you and marked as solved. Thanks.